# fillMaxSize() and textAlign don't work in toolbar jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-toolbar, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have a toolbar having title "Shoes Marketplace", I want this title to be in centre.

My code:

```
Scaffold(

        containerColor = Color(33, 17, 52), // Set the overall background color of the Scaffold
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                colors = TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = Color(33, 17, 52),
                    titleContentColor = Color.White,
                ),
                title = {
                    Text(
                        "Shoes Marketplace",
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    )
                },
            )
        },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    )
```

I have added `textAlign= TextAlign.Center` yet title text is not in centre.

[image: textalign not working screenshot]

If I add `modifier=Modifier.fillMaxSize()`, **whole toolbar title disappears.**

[image: toolbar title disappearing]

I checked official [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/components/app-bars) which does not have much information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is a solution.**

when you `title` parameter in `Scaffold` it is by default `wrapContentSize`.

so you need to make text `fillMaxWidth()` and it will take full width and now `Align` Paramter would work as expected.

**Output:**
[image: preview]

```
Scaffold(
        containerColor = Color(33, 17, 52), // Set the overall background color of the Scaffold
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = Color(33, 17, 52),
                    titleContentColor = Color.White,
                ),
                title = {
                    Text(
                        "Shoes Marketplace",
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                    )
                },
            )
        },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ){
        Column (modifier = Modifier.padding(it)){

        }
    }
```